Should MSP's remove ISP routers?
If an MSP is hired to manage a network, is it typical for them to remove the ISP's router that was previously in place as opposed to just putting the ISP router in bridge mode and forwarding data to the MSP devices. What are some pros and cons to each method? Is it less secure to leave the ISP router in place in bridge mode?

Define "ISP router" in the (on topic) enterprise/business context? In almost all cases, the ISP installs hardware because it has to be there.

@Ricky Indeed, I've never seen an ISP provide a router. It's either just "here are your ports/cables/fiber pairs", or there's ISP-owned and managed media converter/GPON modem/DWDM ONU/radio/… on premises which the customer must never touch.

The same kind of combined modem/router that home users get?

Some people here like to pretend that buisinesses don't buy "broadband" services.

@TooTea I've seen an ISP install a router for a (fibre) leased line; the router was connected by (copper) Ethernet to the fibre termination device. (I don't know why they did that, but they did!)

Short answer: leave it to them
Longer answer: if your ISP doesn't require a special router (technically and by contract), removing the ISP router altogether reduces complexity and simplifies management. Putting the router in bridge mode doesn't provide any significant security. And basically, one decent firewall is a lot better than two half-baked ones.
And after all, contractually it's their responsibility and they decide. You do trust them, don't you?

In general there may be several reasons for keeping the ISP "router".

It may be the only feasible option for some ISPs, which use non-standard technologies or authentication methods.
Even if it's technically possible to use a third-party device, the ISP (or communications provider) may forbid it, or they may refuse to give any technical support if their device is not used.
It almost certainly provides a standard Ethernet interface. Depending on what router the MSP plans to use, it may be difficult or impossible to fit it with an interface suitable for direct connection to the ISP line.

